# Выбрать всё, кроме определённого слова

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как в регулярном выражении выбрать всё, кроме определённого слова (отрицание заданной последовательности, группы символов)?

Можно указать конкретную последовательность, например, `word`, можно отрицание любых из перечня, например, `[^word]`, но как определить всё, кроме word?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dWfd9s/1

Comment: Этого сделать либо нельзя, либо не рекомендуется (решение от XelaNimed не является универсальным, а кроме того, tempered greedy token очень медленный). Просто удалите совпадения из строки или разбейте её на части с помощью своей регулярки.

Answer (score 2):

Вам поможет негативный предпросмотр (negative lookahead):

```js
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit \n a met",
    re = /\b(?:(?!lorem)\w)+\b/gmi;
    // Если необходимо исключить несколько слов,
    // то можно использовать логическое "или" |
    // re = /\b(?:(?!lorem|sit)\w)+\b/gmi
console.log(str.match(re));
```

Поиграться с выражением можно [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/dWfd9s/2).

Comment: Спасибо! Но вот только слово, например, site тоже попадает, а не должно...

Comment: @Имя обновил ответ. Но, по большому счёту, Ваш вопрос предполагает исключение одного слова, т.е. в следующий раз подробней описывайте проблему, чай не на кофейной гуще гадаем :)